# Finding Windows 7 Product Key Before Reinstall

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, product-key

I got drafted into repairing a friend's laptop. He got a virus and after removing it the laptop would no longer boot into Windows. After banging my head against the wall for several days I've finally admitted that at this point a reinstall is the only option. I've already backed up most of his important stuff to an external using a Linux live cd.

Here's the issue: The laptop came with a recovery partition, which is unfortunately not working. So I burned a copy of the official Windows 7 install disk and want to use that. But the laptop is a few years old and the sticker on the bottom with the product key is illegible. To my knowledge the key isn't written down anywhere else, and I don't want to start the reinstall without being able to activate it.

So, is there any way to find the Windows product key without being able to read the sticker or boot up windows? I can access the filesystem using the live cd, but thats about it.

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question and I would like to know it too but have you tried repairing it with windows dvd? If it us a problem with bootloader, it should fix it.

Comment: While I think the question is a good one (and one that is interesting), you will need the OEM install disc rather than the "official Windows 7 install disk" - otherwise they key won't be accepted

Comment: contact the manufacturer for support. if it would boot, there is software that can extract it, but I've never heard of an offline keyfinder.

Comment: Of interest: [How to Recover Windows and Software Keys from a Broken Computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/64600/how-to-recover-windows-and-software-keys-from-a-broken-computer/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover Vista install key from non-booting OS drive](http://superuser.com/questions/273407/recover-vista-install-key-from-non-booting-os-drive), [Obtaining the Windows 7 CD key from its installation files](http://superuser.com/questions/337122/obtaining-the-windows-7-cd-key-from-its-installation-files), [How do I retrieve a product key from a secondary HDD?](http://superuser.com/questions/636568/how-do-i-retrieve-a-product-key-from-a-secondary-hdd?rq=1)

Comment: @khajvah Repairing it with the windows dvd is what I spent the last few days trying :) Chkdsk, auto repair, bootrec, nothing worked.

nerdwaller Thanks for the link! I'll check it out once I get home from work. Hopefully it works, since the laptop did not come with an install disc (that I know of). Apparently Toshiba went the partition route, which would be great if it actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot recover a Windows 7 product key from the system.

It sounds like it's an OEM license, so you may be able to recover it by calling up the maker of the laptop. If it's a Dell laptop, it'll have a service tag, which will allow you to recover the exact key used to install Windows in the first place.

Comment: I am seeing several places that suggest otherwise, what makes you so confident that those solutions do not work?  Have you tried them?

Comment: The "Key Finder" programs that you can find rarely work for OEM installations of Windows; try one out, see if you get anything. No harm in trying!